# AI logic to rotate towards a gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to build a game where the AI needs to keep running away from the player and keep collecting randomly spawning collectables on the map. How do I make it rotate towards a newly spawned collectible object?

Both player and opponent need to move peculiarly, as shown in the code below..

```
if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2 && touch.position.y < Screen.height / 2) {
            Player.Rotate (0, 0, 5);
}
if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2 && touch.position.y < Screen.height / 2) {
            Player.Rotate (0, 0, 5);
}
```

The Opponent also is constantly moving in the forward direction based on the rotation angle, hence just need to rotate the opponent in the right direction

```
void Update(){
transform.position += transform.up * Time.deltaTime * EnemySpeed;
}
```

Here is my code for Opponent AI to find the collectible's position and rotate towards it

```
void AIControls ()
{
    if (GameManager.Instance.CollectibleReady) {
        //rotate towards collectible Item
    Vector3 opponentPos = transform.position;
    foodPos.x = foodPos.x - opponentPos.x;
    foodPos.y = foodPos.y - opponentPos.y;

    angle = Mathf.Atan2 (foodPos.y, foodPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0, 0, angle));

    } else {
      //Wander aimlessly avoid the player   
    }
}
```

This is not working correctly, The opponent wont rotate towards the newly spawned collectible item. Please Help!

Comment: Shouldn't you invert the targetDir? That vector is from the AI to the player, I'd guess you want the opposite or something or some 90 degrees rotation from that vector.

Comment: ohh yes, thanks that makes sense but I am not sure how to do a 90 degree rotation from the vector.

Also, want to know how to go rotate my opponent towards a vector3 point

Comment: (x, y) rotated 90 degrees is simply (-y, x), if you want to rotate it counter-clockwise it would be (y, -x). 
But if you want to rotate a vector with any arbitrary degree.
`
theta = deg2rad(angle);

cs = cos(theta);
sn = sin(theta);

pointX = x * cs - y * sn;
pointY = x * sn + y * cs;`

Comment: wish i paid attention to all the math taught at school. So I tried pplying some trigonometry and have modified my question

Comment: What about `Transform.LookAt`? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Answer (score 0):

I think `Quaternion.LookRotation` can help you - http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html

So you could write something like:

```
var directionToFood = foodPos - transform.position;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToFood, Vector3.up);
```

Comment: This makes it rotate in all axes. How do I stop it from rotating in all axes. Since it is a 2d game I want it to only rotate on its Z axis.

Comment: Sure, but aren't the collectables and the opponent on the same plane?  If so, there will never be a rotation in the Y-axis (assuming that your game is based in the X-Z plane) as long as they don't move up and down on the Y-axis.  If you do need it to be fixed in the plane, you could just modify the `directionToFood` e.g. `directionToFood = new Vector3(directionToFood.x,0,directionToFood.z);`

Comment: So I stil dont understand the concept of lookRotation. I am making a 2D game. The Opponent and the food is at 0 position on Z-axis. I want to give x and y positions of the food to the opponent and make it rotate on its Z axis only to make it point the food. Can you please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after playing around for a while I got what I wanted, adding the code here for someone who might find this useful.

```
void AIControls ()
{
    if (GameManager.Instance.CollectibleReady) {
    //rotate towards collectible Item
    Vector3 opponentPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (this.transform.position);
    Vector3 foodtPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (food.transform.position);
    Vector3 relativePos = foodPos - opponentPos;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (relativePos.y, relativePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0, 0, angle - 90));
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for looking into the matter!